# Defining macros for specific functions in C++

Tags: c++, macros

There are 4 things that I was wondering if I could do in C++ with macros or inline functions.

```
(1) postfix operations in normal types (int, char, etc)

int n = 5;
printf("%d\n", n!)

output: 120
```

---

```
(2) infix operations in normal types (int, char, etc)

int a = 20, b = 10
if(b|a) printf("%d is divisor of %d\n", b, a);
// the symbol | means "divides", this is like (a % b == 0)
output: 10 is divisor of 20
```

---

```
(3) sequential operations in common types

int a = 5, b = 15, c = 20;
if(a < b < c) printf("true\n");
output: false
//doesn't matter if it's made with symbols or words
```

---

```
(4) for each (not using for(auto...) C++11) and 
it may different for lists, vectors, etc...

vector<int> v = {1,3,5,7};
foreach(e : v) printf("%d ", e);
output: 1 3 5 7
```

That's it. Is it possible to make any of these macros in C++ ?

Thanks !

PS: the symbols dont need to be | or !. Since they work, they can be @ or $ or anything. The idea is to be postfix (a@), infix(a@b), sequential (a@b@c) and the foreach may be different, just to be smaller than a normal for is ok

Comment: **Don't use macros**, you just provide inline functions for these snippets.

Comment: Macros can't be used here because their names must be identifiers (not operator tokens like `!`). And C++ doesn't allow operator overloading for builtin types. You could accomplish this with your own special preprocessor, I suppose, but at that point you're not really writing C++ anyway so you might as well use a different language or more conventional syntax.

Comment: I'm curious if I can do it anyway... If the syntax is same as shown, I don't care if its macro or inline... but I prefer macro cos its smaller to code, and the symbols can be other than the ones that are forbidden, no problem with that

Comment: the compiler will automatically inline small functions unless optimization is turned off.

Comment: You can try to look at using the pattern `x <op> y` where `op` is a special object with overloads for `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to give your operators a textual name, you can certainly do 1, 2, 3. I believe 4 is what templates are for, i.e., take std::vector with T as a template parameter. You can inline any of these functions. Note that this code will probably not pass a code review, it's just here for your experimenting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp> // change to <optional> if you have it

#define OPTIONAL_NS boost // change it to std if above is <optional>
using namespace std;

struct Factorial {};
#define FACTORIAL * Factorial()  /* choose operator based on associativity and precedence */

int operator*( const int n, const Factorial& )
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : (n - 1) FACTORIAL * n;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
struct StoreOne
{
    const U m_a;

    StoreOne( const U& a )
    : m_a( a )
    {
    }

    operator bool() const // do this only if U can be casted to bool
    {
        return m_a;
    }
};

struct Divides {};
#define DIVIDES * Divides() *

StoreOne<Divides, int> operator*( const int a, const Divides& )
{
    return a;
}

bool operator*( const StoreOne<Divides, int> da, const int b )
{
    return b % da.m_a == 0;
}

struct Gt {};
#define GT < Gt() <

StoreOne<Gt, OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int> > operator<( const OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int> a, const Gt& )
{
    return OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int>( a );
}

OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int> operator<( const StoreOne<Gt, OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int> >& ga, const int b )
{
    if ( ga.m_a )
    {
        if ( *ga.m_a < b )
        {
            return OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int>( b );
        }
    }
    return OPTIONAL_NS::optional<int>();
}

template<typename T>
void printVector( const std::vector<T>& v )
{
    for ( const T& t : v )
    {
        cout << t << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << endl << "Factorial:      " << ( 5 FACTORIAL                             );
    cout << endl << "Divides:        " << ( 5 DIVIDES 120    ? "Success" : "Failed" );
    cout << endl << "Greater-than 1: " << ( 3 GT 4 GT 5      ? "Success" : "Failed" );
    cout << endl << "Greater-than 2: " << ( !( 3 GT 4 GT 3 ) ? "Success" : "Failed" );
    cout << endl << "Greater-than 3: " << ( !( 5 GT 4 GT 5 ) ? "Success" : "Failed" );
    cout << endl;

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back( 1 );
    v.push_back( 2 );
    v.push_back( 3 );
    printVector( v );
}
```

Comment: while other people just downvoted or said it was useless and should not be done, you were the only one who answered. Thank you !

Comment: :) happy to help and.. no, it's not a 'silly' question. Granted, when you're a C++ programmer in a team you don't code this way but, when you're implementing a task-specific DSL for a group of people (non-C++ staff, say, scientists, economists), then it's quite useful and natural to adopt their syntax. C++ is very strong in this manner, you can re-implement almost any grammar where tokens are textual. Happy experimenting :)!

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you could make a function like `int factorial(int x)` and use `printf( .. factorial(...` but you cannot create operators like this from a macro.
2. No, `|` is already an operator (bitwise or).
3. This is the case anyway,. so what are you trying to do?
4. Why? Just use auto?

I think you are facing the [X Y problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) There is likely no reason to make any of these a macro.